My teacher used manipulations and got 28 ans I used inverse and got 14
Find the number of solutions of the equation in the interval $[0,2\pi]$
$$
    \tan(5\pi \cos\alpha) = \cot(5\pi \sin\alpha) 
$$ both me and my teacher solved till we got
$$\sqrt2cos(α -π/4)=(2n+1)÷10$$
Then from here on he selected possible values like $\pm1/10$ and he got $14$ such solution and then used graph to show that there are $28$ solns but I took cos inverse both side (by taking root $2$ on other side ) and I found that there are only $14$ solns.

Show your attempts please.

Inverse? Edit your post to explain carefully and completely.

@user1176409 how to show my attempt please tell me I am new to the community

Click edit here.

@TedShifrin I edited the post now please tell where am I making a mistake

Remember that $\arccos$ or $\cos^{-1}$ gives you only angles $\theta$ in $[0,\pi]$ (because you have to restrict the domain to get a one-to-one function). Taking $2\pi-\theta$ for these values of $\theta$ will then double the number of solutions.

We need the following facts read from the unit circle:

$\cot x=\tan(\frac\pi 2-x)$
$\tan x_1=\tan x_2\iff x_1=x_2+k\pi$
So. I guess your teacher did "manipulations" in the following way:
$$\tan(5\pi\sin\alpha)=\cot(5\pi\sin\alpha)$$

....
$$\frac{-10\sqrt2-1}2\leq k\leq \frac{10\sqrt2-1}2$$
Then he got $14$ integer solutions from this inequality. Then he thought that $y=y_0\neq0$ lines cut the graph of sine function two times on an interval of length $2\pi$, so the number of solutions is double of $14$ which is $28$. He seems to be correct. I am not %100 sure. Did you check with WolframAlpha?
